# Integral estimate on a two dimensional Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, integration

For my Master's thesis, I'd like to prove the following (but I'm not sure it's true):

On a two-dimensional Riemannian manifold (oriented and closed), for any smooth function $f$, it holds that
$$
\int_M \left(   2 |\nabla^2 f |^2  + \text{Scal} |\nabla f|^2 \right) \text{d} V \geq 0,
$$
where Scal denotes the scalar curvature.
It feel like I have to use some divergence/integration by parts theorem and use that $M$ is Einstein but I just can't make it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to prove this? Is there some motivation?

Comment: Look up Weitzenböck formulae and Bochner identities: these introduce a curvature term that will reduce to $\mathrm{Scal}$ in yr $2$-dimensional setting.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following idenity on a general closed Riemannian manifold:
$$\int_M (\Delta_g f)^2 \, dv_g = \int_M \vert \nabla^2_g f\vert^2 + Ricc(\nabla f,\nabla f) \, dv_g$$
You can porve it by integrating by part the first term and commuting the  covariant derivatives  which make appear the curvature. In your special case $Ricc= \frac{Scal}{2} g$, then your are done.